How would I simply this struct assignment from a set of strings
I think I'm wording this question very wrong.
This is an example of what I have but a lot shorter:
struct example{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}

std::string str[3] = {"a", "b", "c"};
int values str[3] = {1, 2, 3}

if (str == "a"){
   example.a = values[0];
}
else if (str == "b"){
   example.b = values[1];
}
else if (str == "c"0){
   example.c = values[2];
}


The difference being that in the real code it's a lot longer.
Would there be a way to assign via my string array and assign my struct without having to do a big if else that is hundreds of lines long?
I'd love to do it like
example.str = value[0]
but I know it doesn't work like that in C++ and would just lead to a struct error of not having a member named that.
Edit: fixed things that would be caught by a compiler. I could not use a map in this instance due to the code base being a lot more complicated than this.

What is this structure to be used for? Do you really need to have individual and distinct member variable? Can't you use something like std::unordered_map or similar? If you could tell us more about your use-case and the original and underlying problem you need to solve, we would be in a much better position to help you.

(str == 'a') doesn't make sense. str is an array of 3 strings, you can't compare an array with a character.

std::string str[3] = {a, b, c}; You never defined a, b, c. Are those supposed to be strings, e.g. std::string str[3] = {"a", "b", "c"};?

@someprogrammerdude I can't use a map as it doesn't follow the pre existing pattern other parts of the code uses. I cannot give more details as it is work related. This structure gets passed around a lot and used throughout a huge program.

@barmar correct. I made some typos in this as I was trying to write it up fast

You have two arrays named str, and then you use the same name for the key that you're searching for.

You can make use of the offsetof macro. std::unordered_map<std::string, offset_t> offset_dict = {{"a", offsetof(example, a)}, {"b", offsetof(example, b)}, {"c", offsetof(example, c)}};.
